this.state.stockChartXValues and this.state.stockChartYValues are not showing on browser
I am trying to access the data by my API Key
for :
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&month=2009-01&outputsize=full&apikey=demo
but it is not fetching, nothing is showing on browswer:
x: this.state.stockChartXValues,
y: this.state.stockChartYValues,
the below is the code on Stock.js file:
import React from 'react';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';


class Stock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            stockChartXValues: [],
            stockChartYValues: []
            }
        }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchStock();
    }

    fetchStock() {
        const pointerToThis = this;
        console.log(pointerToThis);
        let StockSymbol = 'IBM';
        const API_KEY = 'PGIUZM12MNPJQ8KG';
        let API_Call = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=${StockSymbol}&interval=5min&month=2009-01&outputsize=full&apikey=${API_KEY}`;
        let stockChartXValuesFunction = [];
        let stockChartYValuesFunction = [];

        fetch(API_Call)
            .then(
                function(response) {
                    return response.json();
                }
            )
            .then(
                function(data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    for (var key in data['Time Series (Intraday)']) {
                       stockChartXValuesFunction.push(key);
                       stockChartYValuesFunction.push(data['Time Series (Intraday)'][key]['1. open']);
                    }

                    // console.log(stockChartXValuesFunction);
                    pointerToThis.setState({
                        stockChartXValues : stockChartXValuesFunction,
                        stockChartYValues : stockChartYValuesFunction
                    });
                }
            )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <h1>Stock Market</h1> 
                            <Plot
                        data={[
                            {
                            x: this.state.stockChartXValues,
                            y: this.state.stockChartYValues,
                            type: 'scatter',
                            mode: 'lines+markers',
                            marker: {color: 'red'},
                            }
                        ]}
                        layout={{width: 720, height: 440, title: 'A Fancy Plot'}}
                        />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

No data I can see on browser, just an empty chart.enter image description here
